# Error in Matlab Coder: Index exceeds array dimensions

Tags: arrays, indexing, matlab-coder

I am trying to convert .m script to C++ using MATLAB Coder.

```
function P=r_p(1,var1,var3)
p=[[3,7]              
[10,15]
[6,19]
[21,19]
[43,11]
[969,2]
[113,9]
[43,59]
[21,15]
[6,15]
[10,18]
[3,15]];
tmax=sum(p(:,1))+41;
coder.varsize('x');         
x=ones(9,11).*[0:10:100];   % getting error in this line: [9x11]~=[1x11]. Since size of x is varying in for loop, so i should tell coder that it is variable size, So I used Varsize
for t=11:tmax
  a1=(rand-0.5)*1;
  a9=(rand-0.5)*1.25;
  a2=(rand-0.5)*1.5;
  a8=(rand-0.5)*1.75;
  a3=(rand-0.5)*2.0;
  a7=(rand-0.5)*2.25;
  a4=(rand-0.5)*2.5;
  a6=(rand-0.5)*2.75;
  a5=(rand-0.5)*3;
  x(1,t+1)=x(1,t)+a1;
    if x(1,t+1)<(100-var1) || x(1,t+1)>(100+var1)       % loop 1: x(1,11)+a1 value is is writing to x(1,12) So coder gives error "Index exceeds array dimensions. Index value 12 exceeds valid range [1-11] of array x".
      x(1,t+1)=x(1,t);                                  % In matlab it works fine, but coder throws error. 
    end                                                
 end
```

My question is Let say loop 1,
x(1,12)= x(1,11)+a1 In matlab this assignment works fine, but when converting it is throwing error " Index exceeds array dimensions. Index value 12  exceeds valid range [1-11] of array x" As I declared x as variable size coder should assign x(1,11)+a1 value to x(1,12) but it is not doing, instead throwing error. Why?

Since t is looping for 1289, if I specify bounds for x like
`coder.varsize('x',[1290,1290],[0,0])` then Coder gives error in other part of the code i.e dimensions doesn't match. Ofcourse it should because  dimension of x doesn't match with [ones(12,9)*p(1,2)/9;(P_1s+var3/100*P_1s.*randn(size(P_1s))/2)/9;zeros(30,9)].

1. is declaring x as variable size is correct step or not? if yes then what should be the work around for "index exceeds array dimensions error"

Please Let me know, what am I missing to convert it to C++ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB Coder doesn't support 2 things you're using here: [implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html#bq37dee) and [growing arrays by assigning](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/best-practices-for-defining-variables-for-c-c-code-generation.html#bruzowo) past the end of a dimension.

For implicit expansion, you can use:

```matlab
x=bsxfun(@times,ones(9,11),[0:10:100]);
```

Assigning past the end of an array in MATLAB will grow the array. That's an error in Coder. There are 2 ways to overcome this:

- Allocate your array to have the right number of elements up front
- Use concatenation to grow an array: `x = [x, newColumn]`

In this example, you know `tmax` so I'd suggest just changing the allocation of `x` to have the right number of columns up front:

```matlab
% Current initial value
x=bsxfun(@times,ones(9,11),[0:10:100]);
% Extra columns - please check my upper bound value
x=[x, zeros(9,tmax)];
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan, But if I grow my array 'x'  by using concatenation the new size of x would be (9 by  (tmax+11)). In last but second line of my code `P_1s=[ones(12,9)*p(1,2)/9;(P_1s+var3/100*P_1s.*randn(size(P_1s))/2)/9;zeros(30,9)].*x/100;` i am performing element wise multiplication. To do elementwise multiplication dimensions should match. As size of x is now increased which eventually throws an error.

Comment: I figured as much, that's why I added the comment to check my upper bound there for the number of columns. Looks like `tmax` is wrong for the number of columns. Stick a breakpoint at the line where the error happens and compare the sizes passed to `.*`. That'll tell you what to use in place of `tmax` in `x=[x, zeros(9,tmax)]`. Does it need a -10 or -11 maybe?

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Ryan. Got it! tmax should be 1279 i.e -11. for matrices we initialized by concatenation, what if there is a structure? Maybe I will write a sample program and try to find solution. Anyway, Thanks again Ryan.

Comment: Ryan, I wrote small snippet using structure   
`function []=fu()
structure = struct('a', 5,'b', ones(5,6));
% coder.varsize('structure')
for i=1:10
    structure(i).a=i+2;
end
temp =[1,structure(3).a;
    2,structure(7).a];  
end` 
However, I am getting error **Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 3. The valid range is 1-1.** 


Usually we will work with structures right, so out of curiosity I wrote this function. Ignore if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Exact same idea for struct arrays. Allocate the array up front or grow via concatenation: `s = repmat(struct(...), m, n)` or use `s = [s, struct(...)]` to grow inside the loop.